# How to remove rows if column 1 value is lower than column 2 and column 3?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to know how to remove rows if column 1 value is lower than column 2 and column 3 ?

Here is dummy datasets Updated:

```
c <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
b <- c(40, 2, 40, 10, 50)
a <- c(10, 50, 0.0000891, 60, 100)
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

data <- data.frame(id, a, b, c)
head(data)
#  id        a  b  c
#1  a       10 40 10
#2  b       50  2 20
#3  c   8.91e-05 1 0
#4  d       60 10 40
#5  e      100 50 50
```

In the above dummy dataset we can see that for example: data$id "c", a column value is lower than "b" and "c" column.

After conditional removalhere is the expected output:

```
#  id   a  b  c
#1  b  50  2 20
#2  d  60 10 40
#3  e 100 50 50
```

If its possible tidyverse approach more preferred. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?
Updated to reflect @Mael's comment.

```r
library(dplyr)

#original dataset

c <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
b <- c(40, 2, 40, 10, 50)
a <- c(10, 50, 1, 60, 100)
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

data <- data.frame(id, a, b, c)

data |> 
  filter(a > b | a > c)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   id        a     b     c
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a        10    40    10
#> 2 b        50     2    20
#> 3 d        60    10    40
#> 4 e       100    50    50
```

With updated dataset:

```r
c <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
b <- c(40, 2, 40, 10, 50)
a <- c(10, 50, 0.0000891, 60, 100)
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

data <- data.frame(id, a, b, c)

data |> 
  filter(a > b | a > c)
#>   id   a  b  c
#> 1  b  50  2 20
#> 2  d  60 10 40
#> 3  e 100 50 50
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Do you need `rowwise` here?

Comment: I've just checked this you are correct @Mael  rowwise is not required, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Sorry, but after apply above code to my datasets some rows still has lower value than other columns. For example: column a = 0.000891 , column b = 1 and column c = 0, but this rows were not omitted.

Comment: Could you update your dataset in the question to include these cases so an anwser can be tested?

Comment: Alternatively ask a new question including the cases that fail, referencing this question so it can be seen that the new question is an extension.

Comment: I updated datasets in the question,  thank you.

Comment: You just need to change the filter condition to `filter(a > b | a > c)` I think I may have misread the question initially, as the original filter condition was `filter(a >= b | a >= c)` which tests for `a` being greater than or equal to `b` and `c`. Rather than your request for testing for  `a` being greater than  `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way that allows dynamic selection with `if_any`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data |> 
  filter(if_any(b:c, ~ a >= .x))

#  id   a  b  c
#1  a  10 40 10
#2  b  50  2 20
#3  d  60 10 40
#4  e 100 50 50
```